# PIC16F73 programming

Tags: pic, microchip

[image]I am trying to program pic16f73 microcontroller, but in configuration bit setting there are no options to select internal or external clock.

[image]
Can any one help me to find the solution.

Comment: If you don't have a crystal just use RC and build your circuit like in the datasheet. Personally I'd just buy a crystal.

Answer (score 1):

The PIC16F73 don't have an internal oscillator:
The PIC16F7X can be operated in four different oscillator modes. The user can program two configuration bits (FOSC1 and FOSC0) to select one of these four modes:

- LP Low Power Crystal
- XT Crystal/Resonator
- HS High Speed Crystal/Resonator
- RC Resistor/Capacitor

This controller always needs an external pullup resistor (e.g. 10k) on the MCLR pin.

Comment: so i have to connect an external crystal first with XT Crystal/Resonator CONFIG

Comment: Yes, or mabe try RC oscillator. But they are not really stable. I guess, best is to switch to a modern controller.

Answer (score 0):

From the datasheet, it looks like an external clock is required for PIC16F7X.

If you have a look at the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30325b.pdf)  Oscillator Configurations on the Configuration bits section (Page 91) there are four modes:

- LP Low Power Crystal
- XT Crystal/Resonator
- HS High-Speed Crystal/Resonator
- RC Resistor/Capacitor

On **figure 12-1** of the datasheet, there is how to configure CRYSTAL/CERAMIC
RESONATOR.

By **table 12-2** of the datasheet, the HS mode is for crystal **frequency >= 4MHz** the **XT** mode is for **<=4MHz** and the **LP** is for **<= 200 KHz**.

So the configuration mode is dependent on the crystal resonator connected. For more details datasheet has them all.